# Flex text masking

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible to apply a dynamically created gradient mask on a textfield in flex? If so, could I see an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean a gradient mask? You want the text color to be a gradient? You could turn the text into a bitmap and colorize that. Be more specific so I can help you out more.

Comment: Hello

thanks for the answer. I want make the text alpha changing from 1 to 0 under mask. 

Is this possible?

Thanks

Vladimir

Comment: http://www.insideria.com/2008/01/flex-graphics-tricks-part-1-ma.html has what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for th sample. But in that sample the mask is putting over image. Then I put mask over test - I have problems. Do you have any sample with text masking?

Comment: Well, the point was for you to turn your text into a bitmap, allowing you to mask it like in the sample.

Comment: Oh - thanks I understand. The thing was to set text_txt.cacheAsBitmap = true;